# "404 Resource Not Found" From Azure Blob Storage Document from PUT

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

During a `PUT` request, with the proper Authorization header, which creates a new BLOB, my process is getting a "404 Resource Not Found" error when I attempt to `PUT` a file into a container.

https://accountNameHere.blob.core.windows.net/containerNameHere

The container name and the account name are both correct.

Why is it failing?

---

Here are raw request headers:

```
PUT /testss HTTP/1.1
Host: accountName.blob.core.windows.net
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
0: content-encoding
1: content-language
2: content-length
3: content-md5
4: content-type
5: date
6: if-modified-since
7: if-match
8: if-none-match
9: if-unmodified-since
10: range
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
x-ms-date: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 04:17:59 GMT
Content-Length: 126377
Authorization: SharedKey accountName:MBVLmoxzxZr+tf8EZw2GkbFLEHuNn8FNAaEHrcty/cM=
Expect: 100-continue
```

Here is the string to sign that I sent:

```
PUT x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob x-ms-date:Fri, 09 Aug 2013 04:03:20 GMT x-ms-version:2011-08-18 /accountName/test
```

And here is what they expected:

```
PUT 126377 x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob x-ms-date:Fri, 09 Aug 2013 04:02:17 GMT x-ms-version:2011-08-18 /accountName/test
```

The only difference between the two is the `126377` after `PUT`. That's the content length of the file, I'm just not sure how to remove it.

Answer (score 41):

**1** - In the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) application do these steps to change/verify access.

1. Right click the container's blob in question
2. Select `Set Public Access Level`
3. Set to at least `Public read access for blobs only`.
4. Apply.

[image]

---

*OR* **2** - or In the Azure Portal Panel select

- `Storage account` >
- from `Blob service` Section Select "`Blob`" >
- Select Blob or Blobs that you want to change the access permission >
- Select "`Access policy`" >
- from the Drop Down menu select "`Blob`" or "`Container`" anonymous access based on your needs

Comment: Champion! I needed a hero and you're it. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Have you checked the security settings of the Blob container? It might be that you don't have enough access rights.

Comment: check `Blob service > Container > Access Policy`

Comment: Thank you @Yar!  ----- I changed the access level of my container from `Private (non anonymous access)` to `Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Check your container. In the new portal, click the ellipses next to it and Edit. Then set the Access type to either Blob or Container if you want to allow listing of the container.

Microsoft seems to have bumped up the security and made new containers private by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  I was struggling as to why I could see a Blob in my Container, but could not hit the URL and download it in a browser.  What is the difference between Access type "Blob" vs "Container", do you happen to know?

Comment: @PhilipTenn Blob means the blob is public but not the container, Container means the both the container and blobs are public....

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your storage account
2. Select Container
3. Check the checkbox of your container
4. Click on **Change Access level**

[image: Follow 1 - 4 steps from the picture]

5. After clicking on the button **Change Access level**, you will see the below screen
6. Change the option as per your requirement.

[image: Change the access]

Comment: The access should be granted for users only. No public access should be allowed

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home) to verify that you are sending the request you think you are. You can then compare the Fiddler request with the documentation.

Does the container already exist? It is worth using a 3rd-party storage explorer to verify that it does.

Comment: Just installed Fiddler, soon as I get it going I'll let you know what I find. Yeah the container already exists, I created it manually.

Comment: just edited the question with info from Fiddler. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Figured it out. The PHP SDK from Microsoft is absolutely horrendous. It's truly terrible. They are at fault. I'm working to fix it and then I'll submit pull requests. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share what problem you found?

Comment: Can supposedly send a pull request to Azure, cannot share his solution on SO.