# 404 ResourceNotFound when attempting to browse a container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to browse a container using Chrome, but I'm getting a 404:

```
<Error>
  <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
  <Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:52dfbf9d-001e-00f8-281e-432ff9000000 Time:2020-06-15T14:10:32.4761257Z</Message>
</Error>
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54311541/722393), I've turned on public access for both containers and blobs:

[image]

...but I still get the 404.

I can successfully open/download a blob in the container, so I know I have the correct URL.

How can I browse a listing of all blobs in the container?

**--EDIT--**

Per request, here's the URL I'm using:

https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]

Comment: Are there any IP restrictions on the storage account?

Comment: Can you share the URL you're using? You can obfuscate the account name and other sensitive information.

Comment: @Paolo | No IP restrictions.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS | URL added.

Comment: Provided answer. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to access a blob container and not blob inside that container.

To view the list of blobs inside that container, you need to use following URL:

`https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]?restype=container&comp=list`

and this will give you the list of blobs inside that container.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs

To access a blob directly, you will need to provide the URL of the blob which would be something like:

`https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[blob-name]`